# recording mobile app in jmeter 4.0 on windows 10

Tags: android, windows, jmeter

I searched, but I could not find, so I answered here. 
I wanna record mobile app traffic and request in JMeter but I always get "network error" in-app. When I start recording in Jmeter4.0, nothing happens. On Android device get "network error". I correctly installed  ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA on my android machine and correctly configured proxy. Devices are in the same network WIFI and Android has proxy = laptop ip. I use Windows 10 and Jmeter4.0. When  I used windows 8 or MacOS the problem did not exist but I get a new laptop with this system and I have no ideas where is the solution/answer for my case. 
Please help.

Comment: try Jmeter below 4.0 few months back i also face same problem but with jmeter below 4.0 able to achieve successfully

Comment: I did what you wrote. I deleted cert for 4.0 jmeter and I have installed for jmeter 3.2. Later, I started recording and nothing happened. Exactly the same situation what with jmeter 4.0. I do not have acces to network when I have "start recording".

Comment: thanks for trying.

Answer (score 0):

It might be the case that port `8888` which is used by the [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) by default is blocked by the [Windows Firewall](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/4028544/windows-10-turn-windows-defender-firewall-on-or-off), you might need to create an [Inbound Rule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/windows-firewall/create-an-inbound-port-rule) allowing TCP traffic to port `8888`.

Also make sure that Android device has port `8888` in its proxy settings.

Alternative solution could be using [Cloud Based Proxy Service](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420545-BlazeMeter-Proxy-Recorder-Mobile-and-web-#mobile), it simplifies certificate installation procedure to a single click. As a bonus you can benefit from automatic correlation feature as the proxy is capable of detecting dynamic parameters and automatically creating [Regular Expression Extractors](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) to handle them

Comment: I  have created Inbound Rule for 8888 port (locally and remotely) and situation is the same. Network Error.
I know, that in Blazemeter I can created almost everything but in my company outside apps is very restricted, so I must use Jmeter.

Comment: Anyone have idea?